# Looping SQL Results into a table

Tags: php

I'm just struggling to have my SQL output loop within a table. Currently, it displays one result within the table and the remaining out of it.
If I put the entire table within the while loop, it creates a new table for each row...
Please help!

Code below

```
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        echo
        "<table class='xsmall' align='center'>
        <tr><th>Costume ID</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Size</th></tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        //-----------------Echoing Results-----------------------//
        echo 
        "<tr><td>".$row['Fname']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Sname']."</td>
        <td>".$row['AvgSpend']."</td></tr>
        </table><br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Place the `</table>` outside the loop.

Comment: the closing for the table yeah?

Comment: Your remaining rows appear outside the table because you closed the table inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks you both for the help...Fred, it works so thanks so much man, such an amateur mistake, but hey Im new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "
<tr>
<td>'".$row['Fname']."'</td>
<td>'".$row['Sname']."'</td>
<td>'".$row['AvgSpend']."'</td>
</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```